# Setting default group permissions via SFTP

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, file-permissions, sftp

I am setting up a file server where users log in via SFTP. I want all users to have the same permissions to read and write any file. Since they all have different accounts with different passwords, i end up with something like this:

```
-rw-r-----   1 user1   sharing  308 Jul  6 12:03 test2.rtf
-rw-r-----   1 user2   sharing  308 Jul  6 12:16 test3.rtf
```

The group is called `sharing` which contains all the users. The problem is when files are written, the default permission for groups is read only.

I have tried setting the umask in `sshd_config`:

```
Subsystem sftp /bin/sh -c 'umask 0002; /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server'
Match Group sharing
    ChrootDirectory /files/
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 002
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

The facl for the directory is this:

```
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: sharing
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:sharing:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::---
```

also in these places:

```
init.d/rc:umask 002
init.d/ssh:umask 002
bash.bashrc:umask 002
```

If I log in via SFTP, i get permissions of 640. If I disable the sftp and log in as user1 via ssh, and touch a new file, i get permissions of 660 - which is what i want.

So how can I get this to work via SFTP?

This is debian 7 btw.

Comment: Try the ssd_config syntax over at http://serverfault.com/questions/70876/how-to-put-desired-umask-with-sftp

Comment: yep, i tried that one as well - no luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centos Sftp Ssh - How always create files with rwx-rwx-r-x and always owned by a certain group](http://superuser.com/questions/1066554/centos-sftp-ssh-how-always-create-files-with-rwx-rwx-r-x-and-always-owned-by-a)

Answer (score 2):

## Background

This is ever lasting problem of `sftp` and sharing files. It is because of the resulting permissions are based on the original permission of the file on the user side and umask (`-u`) argument is not forcing such permissions, but only stripping the unwanted permissions. This means that only if user tries to upload file with permission `0777`, it is applied and stripped down to `0775`. Otherwise it is just left as it was. For example if the user has file stored on his file system with permission `0700`, it will appear also after upload as `0700`.

## Solution

Recently we solved this issue in Fedora by applying patch which is forcing exact permission of new uploaded files, which is based on this one:

https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1844

This will be available in CentOS in few months, not sure about debian.

## Workaround

There is no other elegant solution except some periodical running script (from `cron`), which is fixing the wrong permissions. It would be some one-liner in bash, but I guess you can think of some. I can elaborate on this more if you are interested.

Comment: I actually found a workaround that works on debian also - posting an answer

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work on debian using bindfs - which is still kind of hacky but it works. Basically it mounts one directory into another and you can force all permissions to behave however you like. So regardless of how the file is written in the actual directory, the directory served by sftp will always be writable. Now all of my clients can write to files that other users created :D

Comment: Its been a few years but could you expand on your answer and show the important snippets of your configuration ? Especially the part where users in the same group can read/write the files / directories.